# Can someone break down this for loop? Im not sure how the ? and : work

Tags: java, loops

```
for(int i = 0; i < (this.width > this.height ? this.width : this.height); i++)
```

I know it has something to do with an if else statement.  How could I code this without using this type of for loop?

Answer (score 3):

It's a [ternary operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:), and is equivalent to finding the greatest number of `width` and `height`. You could use [`Math.max(int, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#min-int-int-) like

```
for(int i = 0; i < Math.max(this.width, this.height); i++)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's the short (but not very readable) form of:

```
int limit;
if(this.width > this.height)
  limit = this.width;
} else {
  limit = this.height;
}
for(int i = 0; i < limit; i++)
```

Comment: Nit pick: in your code, the evaluation of `limit` happens before the loop, once. In the OP's code it happens every iteration.

Comment: That is correct! That means my code is not the same as the original loop. I still hope it clarifies the ternary operation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're unsure of the meaning this, it's what's know as a ternary operation

```
(this.width > this.height ? this.width : this.height)
```

This is just working out if this is wider than it is tall, if it is then use width if not then use height.

You 'could' not use a for loop for this operation but it would be a hack just to explicitly avoid the for loop and no simpler than what you have there. In this case it's just trying to find the maximum of the 2 values you could use the Math.max to work out the largest dimension, like this

```
for(int i = 0; i < Math.max(this.width,this.height); i++){
    //your code
}
```